# How to make one bone "push" another?

Tags: rigging, armature, bones, constraints

I'm very new to Blender and try to learn to make some stuff.

This is what I have as an in-progress "proof of concept":
[image: What I have]

Three cylinders(top, middle, bottom) linked to three bones. All bones are only allowed to move up and down.

Now the effect that I wish to add is: when I move the top bone downward, it will fist move by itself. Then when it "hit" the middle bone, it will start "pushing" the middle bone downward. So the top bone will never be lower than the middle bone, but the floor constraint is not helpful here since I do wish it to cause the middle bone to move with it when it's necessary, instead of just stopping there. And they will then move together until they "hit" the bottom bone.

And I also wish that when I then start moving the top bone back upward, the entire thing will move in the exact opposite way. This means that the top and middle bone will first move together upward until they reach the original position of the middle bone. Then the top bone will move alone back to its original position.

Is there any constraint or group of constraints or anything else that can help me achieve this?

Comment: Child of constraints(or copy loc)  with drivers come to mind. Local coordinates determining  when to connect / disconnect to the "train"